# is it possible to show action sheet and hide keyboard when we click on a textfield in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uitextfield

I am trying to get value to a text field from action sheet when I click on the text field. I don't want to show keyboard when I clicked on text field.
actually I need the button click property in uitextfield is it possible to do that?

Comment: Why not make a button look like a text field? Touch the button and show the action sheet.

Comment: @JefferyThomas I need the sky floating text field itself

Comment: @JefferyThomas I want to put a button above the text fields there is any easy way to put both with same constraints

Comment: Yes, you can put the constraints on one (doesn't matter which) and the second is constrained to the first (top to top, left to left, bottom to bottom, right to right). That way when the constraints to the primary one are changed, the other once is fit automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UITextFieldDelegate:

1- add the delegate to your textfield:

```
yourTextField.deleagete = self
```

2- Use the delegate like so

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        //call your function here
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this it should work for you, set delegate for textfield first.

```
 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Select", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Yes", destructiveButtonTitle: "", otherButtonTitles: "A", "B")
            actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = .default
            actionSheet.show(in: self.view)
        return false
    }
```

**textFieldShouldBeginEditing:**

> The text field calls this method when the user performs an action that
>   would normally initiate the editing of the text field’s text.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
private var positionArray = ["All", "QB", "RB", "WR", "TE", "K", "DE", "OL", "LB", "EDGE", "DT", "CB", "S"]
```

// 1 Add a delegate to your text field

```
tf.delegate = self
```

// 2 extend your UITextfield delegate

```
  func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

   // to avoid keyboard
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

  // add action sheet
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: LocalString("draft_title"), message: LocalString("draft_select_position"), preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        
     for i in positionArray {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: i, style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
            textfield.text = i
            self.view2021Draft?.positionSelected(isSelected: true, positionValue: textfield.text ?? "")
        }))
    }
    
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        self.view2021Draft?.positionSelected(isSelected: false, positionValue: textfield.text ?? "")
    }))
    
    //uncomment for iPad Support
    alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
    return false
}
```